# Is it possible to create a random .jpg image using NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm creating an application that reads and posts to Twitter and for some reasons i want to add a random created image using NPM. is it possible? do i need a server side application for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you simply can google "create image npm" and you get tons of results!
btw, if you want to create an image you can use:

[NPM Image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image)

install it with: `npm install image`
just read the documentaion in: [npm image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image)

Answer (score 2):

There are two packages available which can meet up your requirements namely, **random-image-generator** and **text-to-image** which can generate you random images.

You can checkout them in the below URL's

**random-image-generator :** https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-image-generator

**text-to-image :** https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-to-image

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @David R, it helped

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, **jidenticon** is very practical on this case. Ideal for unit testing.

https://jdenticon.com/